# How can botox cure wrinkels?

Tags: skin

How can [botox](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Botulinum_toxin) cure wrinkels?

Do wrinkles caused by tension of some muscles in the skin?

Can these muscles be relaxed by hypnosis or training?

Comment: To avoid down-voting of your question, perhaps first read about [Botulinum toxin](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Botulinum_toxin) and if there's something that you still don't understand come back and amend your question.

Comment: @vkehayas you can downvote if you wish; I have read articles about botulinum toxin, but I need positive statement like `wrinkles caused by tension of muscles`.

Comment: I hope you didn't take my comment as a 'threat' but merely as a suggestion to improve the question. Based on your comment I would suggest that you could consider asking that question, i.e. "how do wrinkles form?"

Comment: @vkehayas then I would read about collagen, hyaluronic acid and etc loss which I don't want to

Comment: @vkehayas i.e. I need to clash the fact that botox works and common theories of skin aging

Answer (score 2):

Botox works by inhibiting signal transmission at the neuromuscular junction preventing the signal sent by the nerve from reaching the muscle through the [destruction of the receptors](https://pubmed.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/31114283/) on the surface of the muscle. As the intensity of contractions decreases the overlying skin is able to recover from constant contractions and replenish the lines and wrinkles with collagen. To keep the wrinkles at bay you will have to repeat this every 3-4 months.